# different internet speeds showing different div tags

Tags: php, javascript, css

I have made this site here:
http://www.attractperfume.com

When I view this page on a low resolution setting for my browser. i.e. I am using my tethering to connect to the net and majority of websites are displayed in low res, when I use my phone. My content text disappears and so does all my page content.

When the browser is high resolution it shows up fine (which is the majority of what everyone here will see it as). How do I stop a page loading low res, is there a command?

[image: Mobile internet]
[image: Broadband]

Comment: You might want to read up on responsive web design.

Comment: Do you have JavaScript or CSS doing absolute positioning? Sounds like the coordinates are off the screen in the low-res version or something.

Comment: not related to your question but your site doesn't display properly in 1920x1080 so you may as well look into that as it's pretty popular display resolution these days

Comment: "There are no cancerous pheromones in this perfume" - Good to know!

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a z-index issue?

Comment: You have multiple errors in your CSS code, I would start by cleaning them up. Go here to see what's up: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator